# Callback function pointers C++ with/without classes

Tags: c++, class, pointers, callback, arduino

I got stuck. I am trying to form a function that will eat classless function pointers and ones from objects. Here is my current code that hopefully explains more.

(It should run on a Arduino, so I cannot use big libraries.)

First off, I am using this library for the Arduino:

```
/* SimpleTimer - A timer library for Arduino.
 * Author: mromani@ottotecnica.com
 * Copyright (c) 2010 OTTOTECNICA Italy
 */
```

Which takes functions which it calls on a set timer interval of this type:

```
typedef void (*timer_callback)(void);
```

As far as my knowledge goes, it's a classles function, the webpage *[Pointers to member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html)* got me really far but, not far enough. Probably a terminology deficit on my side.

Now, I have made my own class which I would like in turn to use this SimpleTimer library. But if I feed the SimpleTimer my class functions, it does not like them (what I understand). But how would it be possible to make this happen without altering the SimpleTimer library.

So there is the class Robot, which has `Robot::halt()`. I want the robot to move forward for a set amount of time. Like so:

```
void Robot::forward(int speed, long time) {
    reset();
    timer.setTimer(time, c_func, 1);

    analogWrite(l_a, speed);
    analogWrite(r_a, speed);
    isMoving(true);
}

void Robot::halt() {
    __isMoving = false;
    digitalWrite(r_a, LOW);
    digitalWrite(r_b, LOW);
    digitalWrite(l_b, LOW);
    digitalWrite(l_a, LOW);
}
```

The c_func variable is a classless function at this point, but I would like to use the `Robot::halt` function. I have looked, read, learned but haven't succeeded yet. I just can't seem to wrap my head around this one because I am missing some angle.

I tried:

```
timer.setTimer(time, (this->*halt), 1);
timer.setTimer(time, Robot::*halt, 1);
timer.setTimer(time, &Robot::halt), 1);
```

But it would all amount to the same problem/ me just stabbing in the dark here...

**EDIT**

Earlier, I said not wanting to change the SimpleTimer library code. I want to comeback on this one, I guess altering it there would be the better option.

Thanks for all the current answers already, I was only allowed to flag one as a viable answer, actually everyhting I read here was extremely helpful.

To continue this, changing the SimpleTimer code. This class needs to have a reference to the object that holds my "halt" function, right? So, overloading the settimer function to something that takes my object and my function as two seperate pointers would work...? I think I am getting the hang of this but, I am not there yet with my head.

**EDIT**

I don't know who came with this one again but, anyone finding this thread. If found *[Member Function Pointers and the Fastest Possible C++ Delegates](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx)* to give a very nice introduction in function pointers and member function pointers.

**EDIT**

Got it working, changed the SimpleTimer library to use this Delegate system:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx

It integrated very nicely, and it could be nice to have a standard Delegate system like this in the Arduino library.

Code as in test (working)

typedef

```
typedef FastDelegate0<> FuncDelegate;
```

Code in robot class:

```
void Robot::test(){
    FuncDelegate f_delegate;
    f_delegate = MakeDelegate(this, &Robot::halt);

    timer.setTimerDelg(1, f_delegate, 1);
}

void Robot::halt() {
    Serial.println("TEST");
}
```

Code in SimpleTimer class:

```
int SimpleTimer::setTimerDelg(long d, FuncDelegate f, int n){
    f();
}
```

Arduino prints TEST in the console.

Next step putting it in an array, don't see a lot of problems there. Thanks everyone, I can't believe the stuff I learned in two days.

What's that smell? Is that the smell of...? Success!

For the ones interested, the used Delegate system does not amount to memory capacity issues:
With FastDelegate

```
AVR Memory Usage
----------------
Device: atmega2560

Program:   17178 bytes (6.6% Full)
(.text + .data + .bootloader)

Data:       1292 bytes (15.8% Full)
(.data + .bss + .noinit)


Finished building: sizedummy
```

Without FastDelegate:

```
AVR Memory Usage
----------------
Device: atmega2560

Program:   17030 bytes (6.5% Full)
(.text + .data + .bootloader)

Data:       1292 bytes (15.8% Full)
(.data + .bss + .noinit)


Finished building: sizedummy
```

Comment: Are you able to make changes to the library code? It looks like the only way to get it is to copy it from http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/SimpleTimer#GetTheCode. Is this what you are doing?

Comment: Yes lets change the SimpleTimer code.

Comment: @Aduen when you integrated FastDelegate into SimpleTimer did you have problems with `memcmp` not being declared? Do you have the source code available for your modified SimpleTimer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by making a [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor_%28C%2B%2B%29) object, that acts as a proxy between the timer code and your code.

```
class MyHaltStruct
{
public:
    MyHaltStruct(Robot &robot)
        : m_robot(robot)
        { }

    void operator()()
        { robot.halt(); }

private:
    Robot &m_robot;
}

// ...

timer.setTimer(time, MyHaltStruct(*this), 1);
```

### Edit

If it can't be done via a functor object, you could global variables and functions instead, maybe in a namespace:

```
namespace my_robot_halter
{
    Robot *robot = 0;

    void halt()
    {
        if (robot)
            robot->halt();
    }
}

// ...

my_robot_halter::robot = this;
timer.setTimer(time, my_robot_halter::halt, 1);
```

This only works if you have one robot instance though.

Comment: If that works, then wouldn't `std::bind(&Robot::halt, this)` work, too?

Comment: You _could_ do this, if setTimer was a template and accepted functors. It looks like it genuinely only accepts `void (*timer_callback)()` to me though: http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/SimpleTimer#GetTheCode

Comment: @KerrekSB I always forget about this newfangled C++11 stuff, but I guess it would. :)

Comment: @KerrekSB The backend to Arduino (avr-gcc) doesn't support any of the standard template library so I doubt `std:bind` would be an option in this case.

Comment: It looks like a viable solution, I had to read a little more about the functors and their differences but, I assume this should work on the Arduino. The only thing is, would I be making structs like this for every function I want to use as a callback?

Comment: IF you change the SimpleTimer library so you can use functors ... THEN you can make a functor that takes a member function pointer as well as the object pointer, and that'll give you a lot of the same flexibility

Comment: Sounds like the way to go. I will read into this setup and report back. Like your if-then comment setup, haha.

Answer (score 3):

Since the timer callback signature doesn't take any argument, you unfortunately need to use some global (or static) state:

```
Robot *global_robot_for_timer;
void robot_halt_callback()
{
    global_robot_for_timer->halt();
}
```

you can at least wrap that lot into it's own file, but it isn't pretty. As Matthew Murdoch suggested, it might be better to edit the SimpleTimer itself.  A more conventional interface would be:

```
typedef void (*timer_callback)(void *);

SimpleTimer::setTimer(long time, timer_callback f, void *data);

void robot_halt_callback(void *data)
{
    Robot *r = (Robot *)data;
    r->halt();
}
```

ie, when you call setTimer, you provide an argument which is passed back to the callback.

The smallest change to SimpleTimer would be something like:

### SimpleTimer.h

```
typedef void (*timer_function)(void *);
struct timer_callback {
    timer_function func;
    void *arg;
};
// ... every method taking a callback should look like this:
int SimpleTimer::setTimeout(long, timer_function, void *);
```

### SimpleTimer.cpp

```
// ... callbacks is now an array of structures
callbacks[i] = {0};

// ... findFirstFreeSlot
if (callbacks[i].func == 0) {

// ... SimpleTimer::setTimer can take the timer_callback structure, but
// that means it's callers have to construct it ...
int SimpleTimer::setTimeout(long d, timer_function func, void *arg) {
    timer_callback cb = {func, arg};
    return setTimer(d, cb, RUN_ONCE);
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. I will try this stuff out and report my findings.

Comment: Just make sure you're careful about the distinction between `timer_function` and `timer_callback`, since my patch above is far from complete.  You may also be able to come up with better names :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a non-static member function there - only a static one. The signature should be like this:

```
static void halt()
{
    //implementation
}
```

the reason is that each non-static member function has an implicit `Robot*` parameter known as `this` pointer which facilitates access to the current object. Since the callback signature doesn't have such `Robot*` parameter you can't possibly pass a member function of `class Robot` unless it is static.

So that in your implementation

```
void halt();
```

is in effect

```
static void halt( Robot* thisPointer );
```

and when you do

```
void Robot::halt() {
    __isMoving = false;
}
```

you effectively have this:

```
void Robot::halt( Robot* thisPointer ) {
    thisPointer->__isMoving = false;
}
```

and of course a `halt( Robot*)` function pointer can't be passed in place of `void (*)(void)` C callback function.

And yes, if you need access to non-static member variables of `class Robot` from inside the callback you'll have to somehow retrieve the pointer to `class Robot` instance elsewhere - for example, store it as a static member variable so that you don't rely on `this` pointer.

Comment: Usually C-Libraries have some "void * user" argument, in which you can store additional data (like this-pointers, which can be casted afterwards).

Comment: @nob: Yes, that's pretty typical, however looks like there's nothing like that in this case.

Comment: @sharptooth: However, since the code isn't really packaged as a library (http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/SimpleTimer#GetTheCode) it could be changed pretty easily to support doing so...

Comment: Alright, I think I am getting the point, very nice explenation. So, I am thinking to revise my previous argument, not wanting to change the SimpleTimer code.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand that function pointers and pointers to class members are different not for an arbitrary reason but the fact that instance methods have an implicit `this` argument (also, they have to work with inherited and virtual functions, which adds even more complexity; hence they can be 16 or more bytes in size). In other words, a function pointer to a class member is only meaningful together with an instance of the class.

As the currently-top answer says, your best bet is to go with **functors**. While the `setTimer` function might only accept function pointers, it is possible to write a template function to wrap the call and accept both. For even more fine-grained processing, you can write a template metaprogram ([Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) has `is_pointer`, `is_function` and even `is_member_function_pointer`) to handle the different cases.

How you make the functors is a different story. You can opt for writing them by hand (which means implementing a class with `operator()` for each one of them), but depending on your needs that might be tedious. A couple of options:

- `std::bind`: you can use it to create a functor whose first parameter will be bound to the value you specify - in the case of member functions, it will be the instance.
- Depending on your compiler, you might not have access to `std::bind` - in this case I suggest `boost::bind`. It is a header-only library and provides the same functionality.
- You can use [another delegate implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx). I don't have experience with this one, but claims to be faster than other implementations (including std::function).

The mentioned libraries are header-only, so they probably don't count as "big libraries".