# Functor in callback: compilation errors

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a simple function that uses a callback and I want use functor instead of normal function to be used as callback. But I get compilation error. It seems I missing smth.

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void some_func( void (*f)() ) 
{
    f(); 
}

class Functor
{
public:
    void g() { std::cout << "world"; }
    void operator() () { std::cout << "hello"; }
};

void g()
{
    std::cout << "beautiful";
}

int main(int c, char**v)
{
    Functor f;
    f();
    some_func(g);
    some_func(f);//line 26
    some_func(std::bind(&Functor::g, f));//line 27
    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
g++ 1.cpp std=c++0x
1.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
1.cpp:26:16: error: cannot convert 'Functor' to 'void (*)()' for argument '1' to 'void some_func(void (*)())'
1.cpp:27:37: error: cannot convert 'std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (Functor::*)()>(Functor)>' to 'void (*)()' for argument '1' to 'void some_func(void (*)())'
```

Same story for `cl`

Comment: The type of `Functor::operator()()` is not `void (*)()`; I think it's `void (Functor::*)()`.

Comment: It seem irrelevant. I pass `Functor` to `some_func`, not `Functor::operator ()`

Comment: @Lol4t0: it leads in the right direction, though, since `Functor` is also not `void(*)()`.

Comment: I thought presence of `operator ()` let me cast `Functor` to `void(*)()`, don't ask me _why_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`some_func` takes only real function pointers as arguments, not functor classes. Try using:

```
template <class Functor>
void some_func( Functor f ) 
{
    f();
}
```

Comment: I see. What should I do with `some_func` to take functors & what is the difference with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819580/callback-function-pointers-c-with-without-classes , where `setTimer` _can_ accept functors?

Comment: @Lol4t0: Whether `setTimer` can accept functors is doubtful in the question you linked. See the comments to the aspected answer.

Comment: Oh, I just saw that answer is accepted. Ok, than it's all clear

Comment: And one note also, I hadn't to rewrite `some_func(g);`